# Could not download ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.2)

Tags: flutter

I'm using Android Studio and flutter. I just create a hello world app and run it.
But the console shows

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia X6 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\hupo3\AndroidStudioProjects\startup_namer\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\hupo3\AndroidStudioProjects\startup_namer\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not download ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.1.2/ddmlib-26.1.2.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.1.2/ddmlib-26.1.2.jar'.
            > d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

I downloaded ddmlib-26.1.2.jar, and put it in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib. 
Not worked.

Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking this : AndroidStudio  --> settings-->Gradle --->Android